# How to store application settings that an Admin account can change in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my web application, user accounts' password has expiration dates.

How can an admin dynamically update the lifespan of all account password.

For example, the current setting is 90 day and the admin wants to change the password lifespan to 30 days.

On my previous project, I created a table named 'password_expiration_date'.
which only contains one row (with columns days_lifespan, expiration_date).

I don't know if this method is correct.

Comment: define "correct"? i mean if it works it is correct to some degree. just add a column `pwd_last_update` to users table, and have a configuration database table with `id, name, value` and store your dynamic configuration vars there. then whenever the user logs in it can check the password expiration against the time the user last updated their password and force them to update.

Comment: that's what i was thinking. what i meant for "correct" is "conventional" or "practical" way in such problems.

Comment: this is one of those things where it is largely left up to you. there is no docs on this sort of thing, and anyone saying x is the best way is just citing their own opinion. it is not like with sql queries where you can say this is better because of some quantifiable metric (speed). in any case, do it the way i just described (atleast for storing dynamic config vars as i dont require users to change their pwds).

Comment: i didn't think of it that way. thanks for your help Alex!